# Azure says my query is consuming too much time/resources, but I can't find it in the code

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Azure Query Performance Insight shows a query that is consuming most of my resources (DTUs). It runs consistently approx. 80K times per hour. From my knowledge, it seems like a bug or something is wrong, nothing should hit that often. Azure gives me the SQL, but I can't find the C# EF code that generates it. There are a number of sites using this DB. Given there is a crap-ton of code, there is some lazy loading, and general EF "abstraction", I can't find exactly where this query is occurring. Is there some other place I can narrow down the code/controller/action something?

Comment: QPI is built on top of Query Store which is enabled by default on your database in SQL Azure.  You can use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to the database and review the data there.  It may give you somewhat more information (or be more flexible to navigate).  For example, if it is part of a stored procedure, you can see that.  It can't tell you which app code is submitting it, however.  You can potentially look at sys.dm_exec_connections to see which apps are connecting and perhaps work back to the culprit app + code.

Comment: Thanks Conor, I've hooked up SSMS and it gives me basically the same info. It's not part of a stored procedure. In general it seems you can see the SQL generated by a piece of EF code, but I kinda need the inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your various applications are using different [ApplicationName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.applicationname?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) values in your query string.  Then you can identify which sessions are from which Applications.

You can see the ApplicationName as `program_name` in sys.dm_exec_sessions

```
select session_id, program_name 
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Which you can use to join with sys.dm_exec_requests, eg

```
 select s.session_id, 
 s.host_name, 
 s.program_name,
 r.status,
 r.wait_type,
 r.wait_time,
 r.last_wait_type,
 r.total_elapsed_time,
 r.logical_reads,
 r.reads,
 r.writes,
 SUBSTRING(st.text, (r.statement_start_offset/2)+1, 
   ((CASE r.statement_end_offset 
    WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
    ELSE r.statement_end_offset END 
   - r.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text,
 qp.query_plan
 from sys.dm_exec_requests r
 join sys.dm_exec_sessions s
  on r.session_id = s.session_id 
 outer apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(r.plan_handle) qp
 outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) st
 where r.plan_handle is not null
   and r.session_id <> @@spid
 order by logical_reads desc
```

or as `client_app_name` in an XEvents session

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [queries] ON DATABASE 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username))
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
GO
```

If you are on EF Core you can add [Query Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tags) to passthrough a correlating name from your client code to comments the generated SQL Queries.

But the basic method is to turn on [EF logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3) in your applications and then look for the query text and trace it back to the method that generated the query.

Comment: Thank David, Assuming I re-instrument the applications, where does ApplicationName show up so I can see it?

Comment: The sessions don't really help because these are web apps hitting the db and there are 100's of sessions at any time. I think basically the only way is to rewrite the code to put in  some breadcrumbs and try to figure it out.

Comment: You can use the sessions when joining to `sys.dm_exec_requests` which shows you the currently-running queries.  If this query runs that much, you should be able to spot it.  Se update to answer.

Comment: I know which query it is, I just can't find where in the EF code that query is generated. At the rate it is being called it seems like it should be in some loop somewhere, but I can't find one.

Comment: Right.  That query will tell you what the connection string's ApplicationName setting is, which should tell you at least which application it was.